# Laravel Sorting errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have done all the setting and set-up, and I don't know which mistake I had made since Laravel didn't throw back the error message to me. I wish to sort the (Code), (Description), (Parent_id) and (Status), can someone guide me where I had made the mistake? 
My Objective is to click on the (code) and the system is able to sort in ascending order and descending order!

Controller Code

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $codeSearch = $request->get('code');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('description');

    $sort = $request->get('sort')!=''? $request->get('sort'):'asc';

    $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->paginate(5);


    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($policy = Category::find($category->parent_id, 'description')) {
            $category->parent_id = $policy->description;
        }
    }

    return view('category.index', ['category' => $categories]);
}
```

Index.blade.php Code

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
            <thead class="bg-dark" style="color: #636b6f">


            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>

                <th style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <a href="{{url('laravel-crud-search-sort')}}?search={{request('search')}}&code={{request('code')}}&field=code&sort={{request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'desc':'asc'}}">
                        Code
                    </a>
                    {{request('field')=='code'?(request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'':''):''}}
                </th>


                <th style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <a href="{{url('laravel-crud-search-sort')}}?search={{request('search')}}&description={{request('description')}}&field=code&sort={{request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'desc':'asc'}}">
                        Description
                    </a>
                    {{request('field')=='description'?(request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'&#9652;':'&#9662;'):''}}
                </th>

                <th style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <a href="{{url('laravel-crud-search-sort')}}?search={{request('search')}}&parent_id={{request('parent_id')}}&field=code&sort={{request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'desc':'asc'}}">
                        Parent
                    </a>
                    {{request('field')=='parent_id'?(request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'&#9652;':'&#9662;'):''}}
                </th>

                <th style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <a href="{{url('laravel-crud-search-sort')}}?search={{request('search')}}&status={{request('status')}}&field=code&sort={{request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'desc':'asc'}}">
                        Status
                    </a>
                    {{request('field')=='status'?(request('sort','asc')=='asc'?'&#9652;':'&#9662;'):''}}
                </th>


                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($category as $row)

                <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['code']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['description']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['parent_id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['status']}}</td>

                    <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('categoryController@destroy',$row['id'])}}">
                            {{  csrf_field()    }}
                            {{  method_field('DELETE')}}

                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"  />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
        </table>
        <div class="container">
            @foreach ($category as $row)
                {{ $row->name }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="pagination">
            {{ $category->links() }}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.delete_form').on('submit', function () {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete it"))
            {
            return true;
            } else
                {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Web.php

> ```
>  Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-crud-search-sort'],function(){    Route::get('/','categoryController@index'); });
> ```

My website interface looks like this for now :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use orderBy() to get asc/desc order. follow this:

```
  $sort = isset($request->get('sort')) ? $request->get('sort') : 'asc';
  $$descriptionSearch = isset($request->get('$descriptionSearch')) ? $request->get('$descriptionSearch') : 'id';

  $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->orderBy($column, $sort)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: You will need to specify the column name and sort order. 
...->orderBy('column', 'order');

Comment: Tried ur suggestion but cannot

Comment: oh, sorry didn't notice, @invalid-bot .

Comment: @AndyWOng  try again kindly, there was an issue earlier, and instead id in orderby u can pass the column name ( dynamically from form ) you want

Comment: i have successfully done ->orderBy('id', $sort)->paginate(5);

Comment: but my expected output is every single column and sort individually but not only sort according to the id column @@

Comment: @AndyWOng then pass the column name from your view which you want to sort and then pass that name dynamically inside orderBy()

Answer (score 0):

your query not able to sort the data by defined column then the solution is:

```
$categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')->orderBy($codeSearch, $sort)->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the answer and i get my expected output

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $codeSearch = $request->get('code');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('description');
    // //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $field = $request->get('field') != '' ? $request->get('field') : 'id';
    //This line code is for sorting in ascending order or descending order
    $sort = $request->get('sort')!=''? $request->get('sort'):'asc';

    //This line code is for searching the categories
```

> //        $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' .
>   $codeSearch . '%') //            ->where('description', 'like', '%' .
>   $codeSearch . '%') //            ->orderBy('id',$sort)->paginate(5);

```
    //This line code is for searching description on the index page//
    $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $descriptionSearch . '%')
        ->orderBy($field, $sort)
        ->paginate(5)
        ->withPath('?search=' . $codeSearch . '&description=' . $descriptionSearch . '&field=' . $field . '&sort=' . $sort);
```

> //This link is used for pushing the description value and shows on the
>   parent category, since Laravel do not allow array pass into the
>   pagination !

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($policy = Category::find($category->parent_id, 'description')) {
            $category->parent_id = $policy->description;
        }
    }

    return view('category.index', ['category' => $categories]);
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNfcW.png)